# Numpy: vectorize matrix creation

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

If I want to create a matrix, I simply call

```
m = np.matrix([[x00, x01],
               [x10, x11]])
```

, where `x00`, `x01`, `x10` and `x11` are numbers. However, I would like to vectorize this process. For example, if the `x`'s are one-dimensional arrays with length `l`, then I would like `m` to become an array of matrices, or a `l`x2x2-dimensional array. Unfortunately,

```
zeros = np.zeros(10)
ones = np.ones(10)
m = np.matrix([[zeros, ones],
               [zeros, ones]])
```

raises an error ("matrix must be 2-dimensional") and

```
m = np.array([[zeros, ones],
              [zeros, ones]])
```

gives an 2x2x`l`-dimensional array instead. In order to solve this, I could call `np.moveaxis(m, 2, 0)`, but I am looking for a direct solution that doesn't need to change the order of axes of a (potentially huge) array. This also only sets the axis-order right if I'm passing one-dimensional arrays as values for my matrix, not if they're higher dimensional.

Is there a general and efficient way of vectorizing the creation of matrices?

Comment: It didn't raise any error for me

Comment: @Bazingaa Strange. I double-checked by literally copy-pasteing the code again and got the same error. What version of numpy are you using? I'm using 1.11.1.

Comment: I am using `'1.14.3'`

Comment: _"...I am looking for a direct solution that doesn't need to change the order of axes of a (potentially huge) array."_ `moveaxis` returns a *view* - not a new array and therefore it does not matter how large is your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try a 2d (4d after joining) case:

```
In [374]: ones = np.ones((3,4),int)
In [375]: arr = np.array([[ones*0, ones],[ones*2, ones*3]])
In [376]: arr
Out[376]: 
array([[[[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]],

        [[1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1]]],


       [[[2, 2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2, 2]],

        [[3, 3, 3, 3],
         [3, 3, 3, 3],
         [3, 3, 3, 3]]]])
In [377]: arr.shape
Out[377]: (2, 2, 3, 4)
```

Notice that the original array elements are 'together'.  `arr` has its own databuffer, with copies of the original arrays, but it was made with relatively efficient block copies.

We can easily transpose axes:

```
In [378]: arr.transpose(2,3,0,1)
Out[378]: 
array([[[[0, 1],
         [2, 3]],

        [[0, 1],
         [2, 3]],

      ...

        [[0, 1],
         [2, 3]]]])
```

Now it's 12 (2,2) arrays.  It is a `view`, using `arr's` databuffer.  It just has a different shape and strides.  Doing this transpose is quite efficient, and isn't any slower when `arr` is very big.  And a lot of math on the transposed array will be nearly as efficient as on the original `arr` (because of stridded iteration).  If there are differences in speed it will be because of caching at a deep level.

But some actions will require a copy.  For example the transposed array can't be raveled without a copy.  The original 0s,1s etc are no longer together.

```
In [379]: arr.transpose(2,3,0,1).ravel()
Out[379]: 
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1,
       2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3,
       0, 1, 2, 3])
```

I could construct the same 1d array with

```
In [380]: tarr = np.empty((3,4,2,2), int)
In [381]: tarr[...,0,0] = ones*0
In [382]: tarr[...,0,1] = ones*1
In [383]: tarr[...,1,0] = ones*2
In [384]: tarr[...,1,1] = ones*3
In [385]: tarr.ravel()
Out[385]: 
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1,
       2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3,
       0, 1, 2, 3])
```

This `tarr` is effectively what you are trying to produce 'directly'.

Another way to look at this construction, is to assign the values to the array's `.flat` with strides - insert 0s at every 4th slot, 1s at the adjacent ones, etc.:

```
In [386]: tarr.flat[0::4] = ones*0
In [387]: tarr.flat[1::4] = ones*1
In [388]: tarr.flat[2::4] = ones*2
In [389]: tarr.flat[3::4] = ones*3
```

Here's another 'direct' way - use `np.stack` (a version of `concatenate`) to create a (3,4,4) array, which can then be reshaped:

```
np.stack((ones*0,ones*1,ones*2,ones*3),2).reshape(3,4,2,2)
```

That `stack` is, in essence:

```
In [397]: ones1 = ones[...,None]
In [398]: np.concatenate((ones1*0, ones1*1, ones1*2, ones1*3),axis=2)
```

Notice that this target (3,4,2,2) could be reshaped to (12,4) (and v.v) at no cost.  So the original problem becomes: is it easier to construct a (4,12) and transpose, or construct the (12,4) first?  It's really a 2d problem, not a (m+n)d one.

Comment: This post both generalizes to higher dimensions as explains why it might indeed be best just to transpose the original matrix. Therefore I accept this one.

Answer (score 2):

np.matrix must be a 2D array. From numpy documentation of [np.matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)

> Returns a matrix from an array-like object, or from a string of data.
>   A matrix is a specialized 2-D array that retains its 2-D nature
>   through operations. It has certain special operators, such as *
>   (matrix multiplication) and ** (matrix power).
>
> **Note**
>   It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear
>   algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the
>   future.

Is there any reason you want np.matrix? Most numpy operations should be doable in the array object as the matrix class is quasi-deprecated.

From your example I tried using the transpose (.T) method:

```
zeros = np.zeros(10)
ones = np.ones(10)
twos = np.ones(10) * 2
threes = np.ones(10) * 3
m = np.array([[zeros, ones], [twos, threes]]).T
>> array([[0,2],[1,3]],...)
```

or

```
m = np.transpose(np.array([[zeros, ones], [twos, threes]]), (2,0,1))
>> array([[0,1],[2,3]],...)
```

This yields a (10, 2, 2) array

Comment: My goal is to do exactly this without rearranging the axes (of a potentially huge array) with functions like transpose. Is this possible? As a side note: I was using `np.moveaxis(m, 2, 0)` instead of transpose because now your resulting matrix actually becomes an array of matrices [[0,2],[1,3]] instead of the desired [[0,1],[2,3]]

Comment: I edited the answer to shape it in your desired outcome. `np.transpose` seems to work much faster than `np.moveaxis` from what I've tried. Does that work?

Comment: @Safron_"...I am looking for a direct solution that doesn't need to change the order of axes of a (potentially huge) array."_ `moveaxis` returns a *view* - not a new array and therefore it does not matter how large is your array. This answer at least explains why you cannot create a 3D "matrix".

Comment: @Mstaino Now it works fine. AGN_Gazer Okay, that explains the speed difference. Thanks to both.